# What could cause EXC_BREAKPOINT on Swift sharedInstance return

Tags: ios, exception, swift2, xcode7

I have following crash with `sharedInstance` `return Static.instance!` line:

EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x0000000100da42d8

Crash happened in Ad Hoc release build where there is no debug breakpoints.
According to call stack of the crash `sharedInstance` should already exist at the time of crash (it is first called on app launch, crash occurred on button tap).

Crash occurred on iPad Air 2 with iOS 8.4.0, build is compiled with Swift 2.1 compiler in Xcode 7.1.1

App itself (which calls sharedInstance on launch) and DataSource class are located in different modules. Could it be that for classes from framework with DataSource class static struct is different?

```
@objc public final class DataSource : NSObject
{        
    public class var sharedInstance: DataSource
    {
        struct Static
        {
            static var instance: DataSource?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token)
            {() -> Void in
                Static.instance = DataSource()
            }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static singleton is backed by GCD anyway so this is the recommended syntax

```
@objc public final class DataSource : NSObject
{
  class var sharedInstance : DataSource {
    struct Static {
      static let sharedInstance = DataSource()
    }
    return Static.sharedInstance
  }

  override init()
  {
    super.init()
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but could the syntax I provided be the cause of the crash? Also, with your syntax it's not lazy instantiation which could lead in different behavior.

Comment: The property is lazily instantiated, from the documentation : *Stored type properties are lazily initialized on their first access*. Yes your syntax could cause the crash I guess

Comment: That syntax is from Swift 0.* there, so for now I suppose that the issue was exactly in over-synchronization with newer Swift approach for singletons. Will see if newer crashes arrive :)

Comment: The syntax is safe, it won't crash.

Comment: Also it might be that issue was in stored type property synchronization over optional variable of static struct which I had in old syntax. And compile-optimized unwrapping vs synchronization...